# How to rename the x labels with customed 'strings' one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a plot where the x labels represents weekdays, but rather than ranging from Monday to Sunday, they range from 0 to 6. I want to transform this axis so it ranges from Monday to Sunday (0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday...,6 for Sunday):

```
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
     plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16,9]
     x = Res['weekday']
     y = Res['Ammonia']
     plt.scatter(x,y)
     plt.xlabel('Weekday')
     plt.ylabel('Ammonia Level')
     plt.title('Ammonia by Weekday')
     plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this quite counter-intuitive to solve because `plt.xticks` won't work, and the default for `ax.xticks` seems to start at 1, so it mis-aligns the labels if you don't set it to `range(7)`

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# Create some fake data
x_axis = [[x for y in range(50)] for x in range(7)]
y_axis = [[random.random() * 10 for y in range(50)] for x in range(7)]

# Create figure and axis objects
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_axis, y_axis)

# Your existing code
plt.xlabel('Weekday')
plt.ylabel('Ammonia Level')
plt.title('Ammonia by Weekday')

# Set the xtick labels on the axis object
ax.set_xticks(range(7))
ax.set_xticklabels(['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank's a lot , Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [matplotlib.pyplot.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html).

In your case this will be:

```
xlabels = ["Monday", "Tuesday", ...]
plt.xticks(range(7), xlabels)
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: @roganjosh yes I did, and it works. You can look at this example  if you are not convinced: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py

Comment: @roganjosh I see that there is a problem. I did not realize that `x` was not simply `range(7)`. Fixing it right now.